# trouble in aligning image to vertically centered in android

Tags: android

I am not able to align image vertically centered.What i am missing here?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/moviesSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/movie_prompt" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/Arrowcircled"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
and
try this
android:centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if you add parent `RelativeLayout` with size of `spinner` like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/moviesSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:prompt="@string/movie_prompt"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"

            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/bemoir_splash3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/moviesSpinner"
    android:prompt="@string/movie_prompt" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/Arrowcircled"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/moviesSpinner"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```